# CTS test run taking other version of APK

Tags: android, cts

The device has sdk with AP level 26, and the CTS test is also of level 26. But while running command > run cts-java facing error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Failed to install CtsLibcoreTestCases.apk on 00002474. Reason: 'INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1133462583.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #0): Requires newer sdk version #27 (current version is #26)'

Investigation so far done :
Finding the apk version:

$ aapt dump badging ~/CTS/android-cts/testcases/CtsLibcoreTestCases.apk 
package: name='android.libcore.cts' versionCode='26' versionName='8.0.0' platformBuildVersionName='8.0.0'
sdkVersion:'26'
targetSdkVersion:'26'

Finding device sdk version :
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
26

There is no conflict but still there is error arising. My hunch is the device or cts temp directory has stored previous apk data. I dont know how to remove it. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

have you resolve the issue?
I was experiencing the same and found the following **undocumented behaviour**, see bellow

### Background

As I was testing previously devices based on `Android 8.1 (SDK #27)` I had corresponding CTS and VTS tests organised under a folder, e.g. `TRADFED`, then put under the same parent folder CTS for testing `Android 8.0 (SDK #26)` devices and was getting the same issue with not matching SDK version.
My structure looked something like this:

```
--TRADFED
  |-- android-cts
  |-- android-cts-media-1.4
  |-- android-cts-verifier
  `-- android-vts_81
```

### Investigation

It turned out, that CTS were scanning the entire directory structure from its parent (`TRAFED`) for the test APKs and VTS contains same `Cts*.apk` under the `testcases` subfolder and it was rather trying to install those from VTS rather its own CTS location.

### In conclusion

It looks like CTS are pretty selfish and aggressive and scans the entire parent folder for any suitable `Cts*.apk` apps regardless it sit in completely outside of CTS location.